# Azure Mobile Services with dynamic database connection

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

when we add an Azure Mobile Service we are abled to attach an Azure SQL database, this means for each database in our SQL Azure server, we need to add a Mobile Services.

But what is the best way if we have an app growing up and for each costumer we have a database (each costumer's DB could to grow to 5GB), under this case to have a Mobile service for each database could not be the best choice. I think the best choice could be to have an unique Mobile Service connecting to the different databases (even Servers) depending the user credentials

The question is: Is this possible? someone knows how to do this? The Admin Panel for Azure services is very limited, but if is possible with code will be great

Answer (score 0):

I think Azure Mobile Services may not be a good fit for this scenario. It sounds like you're trying to build a mobile application that you can deploy for multiple customers, correct? And each customer requires a different data source, but the API remains the same?

Currently, Azure Mobile Services doesn't appear to have a solution for this. I'd probably recommend building your own REST API using a technology like ASP.NET Web API, and build up your application from scratch. This way you can deploy individual instances for each customer you require. That said, I hope Azure Mobile Services adds support for the scenario you described in the future. It would be cool to be able to build my service once, and deploy various instances for different apps.